# Can I concatenat a control such as linklable

Tags: c#

I read from a text file, then save the contain of a file to an array

```
string[] SingleArray = new string[] {};
SingleArray[i] = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

So now I would like to perform something like:

```
LnkmyValues_+Convert.ToString(i)+".Text" = singleArray[i];
```

Or If the above can't be done can I have an example on how to putting dynamic linklabel of array on each row or col to a tablelayoutpanel

Comment: C# doesn't work that way.  Are you trying to parse the strings in `singleArray`?

Comment: You should look in to how to do proper binding to controls, it will make this a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Windows Forms with a `Form` called `Form1` that contains a `TableLayoutPanel` called `tableLayoutPanel1`, here is a working example of how you could achieve what you want:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] singleArray = File.ReadAllLines("path to your file");

    // alternatively, for testing:
    //string[] singleArray = {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.microsoft.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"};
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = singleArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < singleArray.Length; i++)
    {
        // create a new link label and set some properties
        LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
        linkLabel.Text = "I am link label #" + i;
        LinkLabel.Link linkLabelLink = new LinkLabel.Link();
        linkLabelLink.LinkData = singleArray[i];
        // tell the label to open a browser upon a click
        linkLabel.LinkClicked += (o, args) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(args.Link.LinkData as string);
        linkLabel.Links.Add(linkLabelLink);
        // add new link label to row i in colum 0
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(linkLabel, 0, i);
    }
}
```